# Bootstrap toggable tab image

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am coding an HTML page that is using the Togglable tabs that is shown here at this link: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

I need to display an image as part of the Notifications tab text, to the left of the text "Notifications".

Here is my code:

```
<div class="bs-example bs-example-tabs">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#Notifications" style="color:#003300;font-size:25px;background-image:url('HomeIcon.png');display:block;" data-toggle="tab">Notifications</a></li>
        <li><a href="#QC" style="color:#003300;font-size:25px" data-toggle="tab">QC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#MySavedWork" style="color:#003300;font-size:25px" data-toggle="tab">My saved work</a></li>
        <li><a href="#MyLinks" style="color:#003300;font-size:25px" data-toggle="tab">My links</a></li>       
    </ul>
    <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Notifications">
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently, the image is shown, however, rather than one image being displayed, the image is replicated multiple times.

Can I please have some help to display one instance of my image, to the left of the text?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using CSS property: `background:url('HomeIcon.png') no-repeat;` so this img will be presented only once?

Also you can add a position where this image (background) will be placed (`background:url('HomeIcon.png') no-repeat left;`,
 `background:url('HomeIcon.png') no-repeat right;` etc.).

Comment: Adding the code no-repeat, with any placement, does not display the image at all.

Comment: Can you check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m4r3U/. Image is being displayed once, one the left.

Comment: Sorry, all working now. I had background-image:url rather than background:url. (I am new to CSS). Thanks.

Comment: Sure. This is updated fiddle so the image is visible on active list only: http://jsfiddle.net/m4r3U/1/